# Multiple SSL on 1 domain/cert/ip/port to multiple servers based on source IP port redirect

Tags: linux, ssl, routing, virtualhost, port-forwarding

I have a very specific question that seems like one that has been asked before in the first place, but it's a bit different and not really a common used case I think.

Is it possible to run **multiple internal (web)servers**, running on **a single host**, using **a single domain**, with **a single SSL certificate**, using **a single external IP-address** and **a single external port**, by using port forward mapping of source IP-address to internal port?

Think of it, as if you want to serve the website www.example.com to 10 clients in different locations, getting different content served, secure over verified SSL, based on the source IP-address they connect from, while you only need one actual server (and one external IP-address) a as host for the 10 webservers and of course only need one SSL certificate.

Further information and conditions:

- The main host is a CentOS 7 box behind a firewall (OpenBSD + PF) using basic NAT
- The internal (web)servers run each on a separate custom port (i.e. 4431, 4432, 4433...)
- Only IPv4 is going to be used, no IPv6
- No SNI is being used/needed (because a single domain is being used)

To set this up for the example situation, by using Apache as example for the (web)servers, I had the following plan in mind (assuming Apache is set up and you have the SSL certificate ready to use for Apache, and no local firewall on the CentOS 7 box is used for the ease of this example):

**Set up static IP aliases to your network interface ethX in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX on the CentOS 7 box**

```
IPADDR=10.0.0.1
IPADDR1=10.0.0.2
IPADDR2=10.0.0.3
... etc. etc as many IP aliases as needed
PREFIX=24
PREFIX1=24
PREFIX2=24
... etc. etc. as many prefix aliases as needed
```

**Set up the Apache Virtual Hosts in /etc/httpd/conf.d/example.conf on the CentOS 7 box**

```
Listen 4431
Listen 4432
... etc. etc. as many Listen entries as needed

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:4431>
ServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /some/directory/www.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /some/directory/www.example.com.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2:4432>
ServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /some/directory/www.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /some/directory/www.example.com.key
</VirtualHost>

... etc. etc. as many VirtualHost directives as needed
```

**Set up client source IP-address to port redirects in /etc/pf.conf of the OpenBSD firewall**

```
match out on $netw_interface from $internal_server1 nat-to $external_ip
match out on $netw_interface from $internal_server2 nat-to $external_ip

... etc. etc. as many NAT rules as needed

pass in quick log on $netw_interface proto tcp from $client1 to $external_ip port 443 rdr-to $internal_server1 port 4431
pass in quick log on $netw_interface proto tcp from $client2 to $external_ip port 443 rdr-to $internal_server2 port 4432

... etc. etc. as many port redirect rules as needed
```

Where the match out rules are for NAT, $client1 is a client external source address and so on, $internal_server1 is the first virtualhost listening on 10.0.0.1:4431 and so on and $external_ip is the IP-address where the A-record of www.example.com is pointing to.

This might not really sound useful, but in the actual situation I have it could be.

Did anyone try this before? And if so, did it work well and was it managable? And is it visible to the clients in any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see why this wouldn’t work. It’s not actually that unusual or particularly complex. Do you have an actual problem to ask about?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-engineering the problem.
All you need is a sophisticated Reverse Proxy server like Nginx. It can redirect requests to multiple back-end servers based on lot of rules/conditions like Source IP, Request header, specific URI, etc..
You can have Reverse Proxy listening on 80/443 port and back-ends running on the same server on other ports or on different servers.
 Main domain/SSL, along with various rules have to be configured on the Reverse Proxy server. Depending on the rule Reverse Proxy will serve the request from specific back-end and that configuration is never visible to end-users.